# Generic Java service with programmatic bean creation does not inject EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, autowired

I have a (hopefully) standard set-up with a bunch of `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Entity` and `@Repository` annotated classes, for example:

```
@Service
public class ChannelManager {
    @Autowired
    private ChannelDao channelDao;

    public List<Channel> allChannels() {
        return channelDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

where `ChannelDao` is:

```
public interface ChannelDao extends PersistentDao<Channel> {}
```

`ChannelImpl` is:

```
@Repository
public class ChannelImpl extends PersistentImpl<Channel> implements ChannelDao {}
```

`Channel` is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "channel")
public class Channel extends Persistent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    // set/get
}
```

`PersistentDao` is:

```
public interface PersistentDao<T extends Persistent> {
    public List<T> findAll();
}
```

and finally `PersistentImpl` is:

```
public class PersistentImpl<T extends Persistent> implements PersistentDao<T> {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> clazz; // gets assigned correctly

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getSimpleName()).getResultList();
    }
}
```

All this works as expected. I am using `<context:annotation-config/>` and `<context:component-scan/>` as well as the `<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" ...>` with a `persistence.xml`. Basically it all works.

But now I want to generalize the ChannelManager since I have many other entities and want to avoid duplication. For example I also need a JobManager with a `List<Job> allJobs() { return jobDao.findall(); }` method.

So I created this:

```
@Service
public class GeneralManager<T extends PersistentDao, E extends Persistent>  {
    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory;
    public void setFactory(AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    private Class<? extends T> impl;
    private T dao;

    public GeneralManager(Class<? extends T> impl) throws Exception {
        this.impl = impl;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postCtor() {
        dao = factory.createBean(impl); // seems to be created and is not null
    }

    public List<E> all() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
}
```

And I updated the context.xml

```
<bean id="jobImpl" class="a.b.c.GeneralManager">
    <property name="factory" ref="autowireFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg value="a.b.c.JobImpl"/>
</bean>

<bean id="autowireFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*GeneralManager"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

And finally added a declaration in the controller:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="jobImpl")
private GeneralManager<JobDao, Job> jobManager;
```

Just imagine the Jobxxx classes to be similar to the Channelxxx ones.

However, when it comes to execute the `findAll()` method in the `JobImpl` specialization, the entityManager is **null**, so something is not set-up correctly.

So my question really is "can this be done"? Although if there is an alternate and nicer way to do this please enlighten me!

**Edit:** Might be of note that I'm using Spring 3.0.5, Java 1.6.0_21-b07 and Hibernate 3.6.2.Final

Comment: I dont see your `ChannelDao` object being initialized in your very first class in the post (`ChannelManager`). Perhaps that is causing the null? I realize you were referring to a different object being null, but they both have the `findAll()` method...

Comment: @gnomed the 'ChannelDao` being wired correctly so I don't think it's that. I have two tests, one using the explicit ChannelImpl and one using the JobImpl and it is always the JobImpl one that fails because of the null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after thinking a bit more about it, I've gone in a slightly different direction by explicitly defining the beans which was something I was trying to avoid. But it is working for me. I still don't know if what I was trying to do was just not possible because of type erasure.

My code now looks like:

```
public class GeneralManager<T extends PersistentDao, E extends Persistent>  {
    private T dao;
    public void setDao(T dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    ...
}
```

with the controller using:

```
@Autowired
private GeneralManager<ChannelDao, Channel> channelManager;

@Autowired
private GeneralManager<JobDao, Job> jobManager;
```

and context.xml now has:

```
<bean id="jobManager" class="com.a.b.service.EntityManager" p:dao-ref="jobImpl"/>
<bean id="jobImpl" class="com.a.b.dao.JobImpl"/>
<bean id="channelManager" class="com.a.b.service.EntityManager" p:dao-ref="channelImpl"/>
<bean id="channelImpl" class="com.a.b.dao.ChannelImpl"/>
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

why not simply use spring-data project? it does exactly what you need and more.

Comment: At the time I was on that project, [*Spring Data*](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) was not released! It might have been in development but I couldn't use milestone releases on that project so it wasn't an option unfortunately.